# Python: If a string is found, stop searching for that string, search for the next string, and output the matching strings

Tags: string, python-3.x

This code outputs the matching string once for every time it is in the file that is being searched (so I end up with a huge list if the string is there repeatedly). I only want to know if the strings from my list match, not how many times they match. I do want to know which strings match, so a True/False solution does not work. But I only want them listed once, each, if they match. I do not really understand what the pattern = '|'.join(keywords) part is doing - I got that from someone else's code to get my file to file matching working, but don't know if I need it. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
# declares the files used
filenames = ['//Katie/Users/kitka/Documents/appreport.txt', '//Dallin/Users/dallin/Documents/appreport.txt' ,
             '//Aidan/Users/aidan/Documents/appreport.txt']

# parses each file
for filename in filenames:
    # imports the necessary libraries
    import os, time, re, smtplib
    from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc

    # finds the time the file was last modified and error checks
    try:
        st = os.stat(filename)
    except IOError:
        print("failed to get information about", filename)
    else:
        # creates a list of words to search for
        keywords = ['LoL', 'javaw']
        pattern = '|'.join(keywords)

        # searches the file for the strings in the list, sorts them and returns results
        results = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
                if matches:
                    results.append((line, len(matches)))

        results = sorted(results)

        # appends results to the archive file
        with open("GameReport.txt", "a") as f:
            for line in results:
                f.write(filename + '\n')
                f.write(time.asctime(time.localtime(st[ST_MTIME])) + '\n')
                f.write(str(line)+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should work. Note that this only keeps track of which words were found, not which words were found *in which files*. I couldn't figure out whether or not that's what you wanted.

```
import fileinput

filenames = [...]

keywords = ['LoL', 'javaw']

# a set is like a list but with no duplicates, so even if a keyword
# is found multiple times, it will only appear once in the set
found = set()

# iterate over the lines of all the files
for line in fileinput.input(files=filenames):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in line:
            found.add(keyword)

print(found)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep track of which keywords are present in which files, then I'd suggest keeping a set of (filename, keyword) tuples:

```
filenames = [...]
keywords = ['LoL', 'javaw']
found = set()

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            for keyword in keywords:
                if keyword in line:
                    found.add((filename, keyword))

for filename, keyword in found:
    print('Found the word "{}" in the file "{}"'.format(keyword, filename))
```

Comment: I do want it to tell me which file the keywords are found in, so thanks. This is definitely more efficient than my original code, and it appears to work. I will do some more testing. Thanks!